# Editing JavaFX 2.2 TabPane in Scene Builder 2

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, scenebuilder

I've faced the following problem when editing TabPane (JavaFX 2.2) in Scene Builder 2:

My app contains 5 tabs in TabPane. When I enter the last tab and try to select any of its child nodes, say a textfield, the editor jumps to the first tab. The issue occurs for any other tab in the group (i.e., 2nd, 3rd, 4th).

The only method for editing a node within those tabs is selecting it in a hierarchy tree and then manipulate as needed.

Does anybody know how to resolve the problem?

Comment: i think you have bug in your scene builder...

Comment: Yeah, it looks like this. I keep downloading new builds but the problem persists